# List inside List,I want to do pagination of inside list items in c# Linq or Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to do paging in c#. but scenario is quite complex. Please see below details.

I have a Main List A. Inside List A, There is another List B.Now List B has multiple List C for each index. I want to perform pagination on List C using C# Linq or Lambda.

- List A

  - List B[0]

    - List C  [with different Category(Assume length=4)]
  - List B[1]

    - List C  [with different Category(Assume length=10)]
  - List B[2]

    - List C  [with different Category(Assume length=35)]

List B length is dynamic and also in each index of List B, List C also will be dynamic length.

Now i want to perform paging on List C All Count 4+10+35 records. 
How can i do this?

Code:

```
List<MenuItemDetails> newMenuItemList = new List<MenuItemDetails>();

foreach (var menuli in output.GroupMenuCategories)
{
    foreach (var item2 in menuli.MenuItems)
    {
        newMenuItemList.Add(item2);
    }
}

var result = newMenuItemList.Skip((input.PageIndex - 1) * input.PageSizeSelected)
                            .Take(input.PageSizeSelected);
```

I tried to put List C items in new list and then applied paging, Now what should i do further to put in main List A.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Also what's the purpose of A? I mean having a `List` with only one element (`List B`) in it?

Comment: I have output object, in output object i have a List A and some parameters, in List A i described the detail.  I tried putting all elements to a new list and then new list paginated. after new list pagination i am unable to update List B items. So I was thinking the better way to do this. Question Edited.

Comment: "unable to update List B items": there are things you want to do which you didn't tell us about yet. Otherwise it sould be easy to flatten the lists (`.SelectMany`) and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses **MoreLinq** and illustrates the use of "Batch".  I understand that the question did not include MoreLinq, but because the question was general, noting "c# Linq or Lambda", I thought that this provided an attractive solution.

```
result = output.GroupMenuCategories
.SelectMany(MenuItems => MenuItems.SelectMany(x => x))
.Batch(PageSizeSelected).Skip(PageIndex - 1).Take(1).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could flatten the structure using `SelectMany`. That way you end up with a structure that's a lot easier to perform paging on. E.g.

```
var listC1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var listC2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var listC3 = new List<int> { 8, 9 };

var listB1 = new List<List<int>> { listC1, listC2 };
var listB2 = new List<List<int>> { listC3 };

var listA1 = new List<List<List<int>>> { listB1, listB2 };

var flatList = listA1.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y)).ToList();

var pageSize = 3; //pages -> 1,2,3 | 4,5,6 | 7,8,9
var getPage = 3; //page 3 -> 7,8,9
var getItem = 2; //item 2 -> 8

var result = flatList.Skip((getPage - 1) * pageSize + (getItem - 1)).FirstOrDefault();
//result -> 8
```